# When using *ngIf offsetHeight not working

Tags: javascript, angular

If I am using `offsetHeight` on the element without `*ngIf` it gives me the height, but when I am trying to use it with `*ngIf` it gives me error, that the `element is null`. I have no idea why it is... Thanks for every help!

The `.ts`:

```
export class CvDesignComponent implements OnInit {
  isUser = true;
  
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const element = document.getElementById("element");
    console.log(element.offsetHeight);
  }
}
```

The `.html`:

```
<div id="element" *ngIf="isUser">
  <h2>aaaa</h2>
  <h2>aaaa</h2>
  <h2>aaaa</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: can you put your code sample @gmark11

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please write exactly your codes

Comment: I have updated the question with the code.

Comment: when we use ngIf on element .It will remove element from dom if  the condition is false ,that's why you are getting null.

Comment: @Chellappanவ And what should I do, to make it work?

Comment: instead of ngIf use [hidden] attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use hidden because , **div id="element"** is not created.

```
<div id="element" [hidden]="isUser">
  <h2>aaaa</h2>
  <h2>aaaa</h2>
  <h2>aaaa</h2>
</div>
```